# EBS or Instance Storage for MongoDB in EC2?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, cassandra

Cassandra recommends using instance local storage for EC2 deployments instead of EBS

I am deploying MongoDB in EC2... should I also be using instance local storage instead of EBS PIOPS?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slide about using Hybrid (Instance store and PIOPS EBS) of MongoDB on EC2.
http://www.slideshare.net/mongodb/world-high-performance-mongo-db-on-ec2-20140620

### Related topic:

Instance store is super fast - https://gist.github.com/ktheory/3c3616fca42a3716346b

### Conclusions:

Instance-store is over 5x faster than EBS-SSD for uncached reads.
Instance-store and EBS-SSD are equalivent for cached reads.
Instance-store is over 10x faster than EBS-SSD for writes.

### Special notes:

Ephemeral storage or instance-store DOES persist across reboots of an instance! It does not persist across a stop/start, nor a termination, nor some instance hardware failures.

Answer (score 2):

The MongoDB manual has a section with [EC2 storage considerations](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/platforms/amazon-ec2/#storage-considerations) including the general recommendation to use EBS-optimized EC2 instances with provisioned IOPS (PIOPS) EBS volumes.

There are several good reasons to use EBS over local storage:

- Local storage (or "Instance Store" in EC2 terms) is ephemeral and introduces potential data loss scenarios on instance stop/start/terminate as well as hardware failure (see AWS docs on [Instance Store Lifetime](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html#instance-store-lifetime)).
- While an Instance Store is dedicated to a particular instance, the disk subsystem is shared among instances on the host server hardware. As with regular EBS volumes, contention for a shared resource can lead to unpredictable I/O behaviour. Provisioned IOPS EBS volumes will provide more predictable I/O performance for an active database workload -- no spikes of higher than expected performance, but also no troughs of decreased performance.
- The sizes of Instance Stores are [determined by the instance type](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html#instance-store-volumes). EBS volumes can be provisioned independently to meet your storage and performance requirements.
- If you want to change your instance types, EBS volumes can be re-attached to a new instance in the same availability zone.
- EBS volumes can be combined using RAID for additional capacity or redundancy.
- EBS volumes support [asynchronous snapshots](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-creating-snapshot.html), which are a common [backup strategy](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/backup-and-restore-mongodb-on-amazon-ec2/#backup-the-database-files).
- EBS volumes can support [encryption for data at rest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSEncryption.html) for most instance types.

Answer (score 0):

EBS is recommended because it provided by more than one actual drive with 2ms transaction commit between mirror drives. EBS itself is fast enough and can reach 500+MB/sec for read and write.

Linux kernel this is what affect IOPS dramatically, see what Pinterest engineers investigated:

> Final choice: kernel 3.18.7 + XFS + 64K RAID block size.
>
> •  Best overall performance for async random read.
>
> •  Very competitive performance everywhere else.
>
> •  Networking-related kernel bugs (Xen-specific) in 3.13 that aren’t
>   fixed until 3.16.

https://www.percona.com/live/mysql-conference-2015/sites/default/files/slides/all_your_iops_are_belong_to_usPLMCE2015.pdf